# How to do useState in this case, I can't add component with props

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I learn ReactJs and JavaScript and got stuck a bit

If I do like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const addData = val => {
    setData([...data, val]);
  };
```

It work as expected every time I run that `addData` the `data` will have one more `val` merging into it ok

But when I like this:

```
const addData = val => {
    setData([...data, File: file={val}]);
};
```

And the `File` is this simple:

```
const File = (file) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    // do stuff
    return (
        <Return something with props file />
    );
};

export default File;
```

Then I get error I don't know how to give `val` to `File` before I add `File` to `data`

I tried like `(File: File={val})` but no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is with `File: file={val}`. You have an array of objects so you should add a new object rather then a property. for that. you need to add this into a {}. Second, when creating a structure and asaigning values, use `:` not `=`. and 3rd - dont suround ur `val` in {}. Make it a simple `val`. If you wish to pass data to val, assuming it some sort of component, make it into an arrow function and load it as a component `() => <Val />`. NOTE, it has to start with a capital letter.

Here is a demo I made similar to what you want by my understandings.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const File = ({ file }) => {
    return <div>{file}</div>;
  };

  const clickMe = () => {
    setData([...data, { File: () => <File file={"some file name"} /> }]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clickMe}>Add</button>
      {data && data.map(({ File }, i) => <File key={i} />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Whenever you click a button, a new component, called `File` will be added to state `data` and will pass a prop `file` into it. and in render all the data form `data` will be rendered.

NOTE You may use `File: <File file={"some file name"} />` instead of using an arrow function `File: () => <File file={"some file name"}`. But this may create some issues and will load the component `File` when adding it to `data` instead of loading in render. hence an arrow function is a better and recomended way to go.

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-sea-svhbs?file=/src/App.js:0-441